# Proper scoping to instantiate a Connection() object in Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm running a Flask-based web app that uses Mongodb (with Pymongo for use in Python).  Nearly every view access the database, so I want to make the most effective use of memory and CPU resources.  I'm unsure what the most efficient method is for instantiating pymongo's Connection() object, which is used access and manipulate the database.  Right now, I declare `from pymongo import Connection` at the top of my file, and then at the beginning of each view function I have:

```
def sampleViewFunction():
    myCollection = Connection()['myDB']['myCollection']
    ## then use myCollection to manipulation the database
    ## more code...
```

The other way I could do it is declare at the top of my file:

```
from pymongo import Connection
myCollection = Connection()['myD']['myCollection']
```

And then later on, your code would just read:

```
def sampleViewFunction():
    ## no declaration of myCollection since it's a global variable
    ## then use myCollection to manipulation the database
    ## more code...
```

So the only difference is the declaration scope of `myCollection`.  How do these two methods differ in the way memory is handled and CPU consumption?  Since this is a web application, I'm thinking about scenarios where multiple users are the site simultaneously.  I imagine there's a difference in the lifespan of the connection to the database, which I'm guessing could impact performance.

Comment: Actually, for someone who's fairly new to databases that's not obvious at all.  I don't understand the intricacies of database connections and what it takes to establish one.  And being that Python is a very high-level language, I think it's perfectly reasonable to ask how it handles subtle differences like this one.  Seriously?  You downvoted me on this?

Comment: J-bob - your question is reasonable, don't worry, some people have....issues and will eventually be flagged/downvoted into oblivion - if I knew more python I would answer it myself, but I can tell you that generally the connection pooling code should handle most of this for you, the CPU overhead will be negligible compared to memory (normally) - the default stack size for MongoDB connections is 1MB, so that is usually the major resource consumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the second method. When you create a connection in pymongo you by default create a connection pool. See the documentation for more details see [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/connection.html). This is the correct way of doing things. The default max_pool_size is 10 so this will give you 10 connections to your mongod instance(s). If you did it the other way and created a pool per function call you would

1. Be creating and destroying a connection with each function call which is wasteful of resources - both RAM and CPU.
2. Have no control over how many connections your code is going to create to the mongod - you could flood the mongod with connections

Comment: Ok, that answers my question.  But then that makes me think - should I further broaden the scope of the `myCollection` variable?  This is a sizable app with a "main.py" file that is imported into many other files.  Would it make sense to declare `myCollection` in "main.py" and then import and use it everywhere?

Comment: Yes it would also be good idea to share one global connection